# Google Spreadsheet API Inserting Images

Tags: api, google-sheets

Is there way to insert images through the google spreadsheet api?

I've looked at the docs, but other than insert/update/delete rows, there aren't any mentions of other data related to the worksheet such as the images.

For example, on excel images are attached to the worksheet instead of any specific cell. So you would have to insert remove images from the worksheet then place it over any specific cell position.

any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately you can't upload files via google spreadsheet api. Uploading is possible via google docs api (perhaps you could link it through there).

Comment: yeah, after all there was no way to attach an image the way excel would let you. I'll just give your answer as the accepted one

Comment: any updates about this? maybe in version SpreadSheet API 3.0?