# Insert or edit an Image in worksheet using Google Spreadsheets API 3.0

Tags: java, api, google-sheets-api

I am using the Google SpreadSheets API 3.0 to create and edit spreadsheets.

I need to insert or modify an existing image on the worksheet.

I tried using the *=IMAGE('URL')* function, but I get an *'Analysis error'* error in random cases.

*Three years ago (Nov 19 '10), somebody posted a similar question:

[google-spreadsheet-api-inserting-images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4227118/google-spreadsheet-api-inserting-images)*

**Maybe now its possible with version 3.0?**

Comment: Sounds Strange, I am able to move these formulas from cell to cell with no problem. Never had the need to insert from scratch. I am using double quotes, does not look to work with single quotes.

Comment: I was strange. Some hours later the IMAGE() function was functioning with no problem.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried myself (so please show some mercy) but what about using the [insertImage](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#insertimageblob-column-row) function as on the example here [Insert image in a spreadsheet](https://developers.google.com/adwords/scripts/docs/examples/spreadsheetapp#insert-image-in-a-spreadsheet)?